# Cannot install viber on Ubuntu 14.04 and 18.04

Tags: viber

I downloaded a Viber deb package from the official website (August 2018). But after trying to install it I get

```
./viber.deb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./viber.deb: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and 18.04.

Comment: Perhaps the package owners can help better!

Comment: Did anyone else have such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. I tried to install the deb package simply with

```
./viber.deb
```

but the correct way is

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

And it worked.